# URL mapping is not available in activeweb 2.0

Tags: javalite, activeweb

In activeweb 2.0, if there is a space in the tomcat installation directory, then there will be no packages, so can not found the correct Controller and action.

Because the space will be replaced with `'%20'` when we use the classLoader get current class's directory.

there is the code in `org.javalite.activeweb.ControllerPackageLocator`

**source code**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel this is a defect in the framework, please file a new issue here: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/issues

Having spaces in directory and files names will get you in trouble universally.